# PostgreSQL ODBC 64 bit driver results in "architecture mismatch"

Tags: postgresql, 64-bit, odbc, drivers

I am running Win 7 64, the latest PostgreSQL 64 bit, and I installed the 64 bit ODBC driver (0310-64). Using the two ODBC control panels, I can create both a 32 and a 64 bit connection. Both test ok.

In VS 2010 Express, I installed MS's ODBC driver 1.0.4030.0. I can connect to the 32 bit DSN, but the 64 bit one gives the the architecture mismatch error.

This doesn't make sense because I set up the 64 bit DSN on the 64 bit ODBC control panel, where I was given 64 bit PG as an option (unlike on the 32 bit CP). I selected the UNICODE version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work with 64 bit DSN and Visual C# 2010 Express Edition edit project settings file .csproj (e.g. WindowsFormsApplication1.csproj) and set **PlatformTarget** property to **x64**:

```
<PlatformTarget>x64</PlatformTarget>
```

Futhermore you don't need to install Microsoft ODBC .NET Data Provider driver externally, because it's included in .NET as [`System.Data.Odbc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.aspx) namespace.

Example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("dsn=PostgreSQL35W");
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("SELECT version()", cn);
    cn.Open();

    richTextBox1.AppendText(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

    cn.Close();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Also consider use of [Npgsql](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/) instead. It seems to be pretty common PostgreSQL interface for .NET.

Comment: That worked, thanks! But... why wouldn't .Net naturally go for the 64 bit ODBC since I'm running a 64 bit OS?

Comment: Does Npgsql have any advantages over ODBC? I was simply following instructions on PostgreSQL's site (the ODBC route).

Comment: I thought about it and I suspect assembly interoperability with 32 bit systems (however I am not .NET expert). Npgsql is written 100% in C#, it has support for Entity Framework and generally has tighter integration with PostgreSQL.